# Ubuntu 22.04 System Settings will not open

Tags: 22.04, settings, gnome-control-center

I tried the following commands. Both ran successfully, no errors.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```

Both of these commands produced "Bus error (core dumped)":

```
gnome-control-center display
gnome-control-center
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Ubuntu's setting are accessible by clicking in the upper right corner of the desktop (where the clock is located), then select *"Settings"*. No need to install any extra software.

Comment: I am trying to open Settings to change the sleep/suspend setting. I clicked on Settings in the drop down in the upper right. I can see the app trying to run in the top bar but it fails. I also tried to open it from the Applications menu in the top bar, in terminal, and list of software. All have failed.